# Troubleshooting issue with reading user data from Realtime Firebase in Android app

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to read the users in use from the Realtime Firebase and display their email in an EditText when I click the button, but the user's email is not showing up and I'm not getting any errors in the debug or Logcat.

Firebase Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLCTi.jpg

class Travel : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var db: DatabaseReference
//private lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
//lateinit var etdata: EditText

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel)

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
}
fun onData(view: View) {
        // Read user data from the database using ValueEventListener
        val userId = auth.currentUser?.uid
        //val userRef = userId?.let {db.child("users").child(userId) }
        val userRef = userId?.let {db.child(userId) }
        userRef?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                // Handle retrieved user data here
                val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Register.User::class.java)
                Log.d(TAG, "Dados do usuário: $user")
                // Update the EditText with the retrieved user data
                val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edData)
                //editText.setText(users?.email)
                Log.d(TAG, "EditText view: $editText")
                if (user != null) {
                    editText.setText(user.email)
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User is null")
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                // Handle errors here
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
            }
        })
}

fun onTerminar(view: View) {
    val intent = Intent(this@Travel,CarActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code.

Comment: This code retrieves the name of the user who logged in.